# swift when value changes of uipickerview in uitableviewcell, I need to upate label in viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipickerview, viewcontroller

I have a uipickerview inside a tableviewcell. The cells are dynamically created. When the value in the uipickviewer is changed it automatically updated a label in the viewcontroller but I'm unable to do that. So how can I get the uipickerview value in the viewcontroller. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Use delegates `UIPickerViewDelegate `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` in your view controller and then set the picker's delegate to the VC.

When the picker changes, the delegate's `pickerView(_:didSelectRow:inComponent:)` will be called.

Comment: Oh perfect. Sometimes it is that easy. Thanks.